# Deleting Chrome HSTS for facebook.com not working

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, hsts

I am currently doing some debugging on my website which involves calling the facebook API.

I've installed dnsmasq to work with my mac os X to redirect all request to facebook.com to 127.0.0.1

I have a echo server which will print out all the raw http request header on port 80 on my laptop.

Now comes my problem. When I access facebook.com, I realize chrome will automatically forward http:// to https:// for facebook.com

I googled and found the way of deleting this HSTS issue. I visit `chrome://net-internals#hsts` to see something like this:

[HSTS chrome image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gCZ22.png)

After entering "facebook.com" under "Delete domain", I can still query "facebook.com" in the input box below.

I tried clearing all user data on chrome, closing and reopening chrome and even using incognito mode.

- Why is chrome still redirecting all request to facebook.com to https?
- How can I disable this if `chrome://net-internals#hsts` is not
  reliable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The text next to the `Delete domain` box on `chrome://net-internals/#hsts` clearly states that [preloaded entries](https://hstspreload.org/) cannot be deleted. [This feature request](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=483634) was closed as WontFix in the Chrome bug tracker.

[image: Text showing "you cannot delete preloaded entries]

`facebook.com` and quite a few of its subdomains are included in Chrome's [preload list](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/net/http/transport_security_state_static.json).

Answer (score 0):

You could use another domain name for your tests.

Just make api-calls to `facebook-api-test.com`, map that domain to localhost and proxy the calls.