# Dnsmasq failing to catch 307 redirect for https?

Tags: google-chrome, redirect, ssl, dnsmasq, hsts

I am currently doing some debugging on my website which involves calling the facebook API. I've installed dnsmasq to work with my mac os X to redirect all request to facebook.com to 127.0.0.1

This is my entry in dnsmasq.conf:

> address=/facebook.com/127.0.0.1

I also have `/etc/resolver/com` with `nameserver 127.0.0.1`

When I turn dnsmasq on, visiting facebook.com will result in a PAGE NOT FOUND error in chrome. This shows that my dnsmasq is working.

However, I noticed that chrome will redirect http://www.facebook.com to https://www.facebook.com due to HSTS. I went on to chrome://net-internals#hsts to delete facebook.com's entry.

The strange thing is, when I am debugging, I see that facebook.com is indeed returning 307 redirects for http://www.facebook.com (See image)

[image]

This is very strange because the domain facebook.com is currently resolved to be 127.0.0.1 on my computer! Furthermore, when I dig more into the request, I do see that the request is valid:

[image]

**Where is this 307 redirect coming from if facebook.com is unresolvable?**

Comment: You probably posted this under a different account a few minutes earlier. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41239186/deleting-chrome-hsts-for-facebook-com-not-working. If it wasn't you, quite a coincidence!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

307 is an internal browser based redirect for HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS). It does not come from the server - it's a fake response created by the browser.